# Json serializer Django, сериализация модели

Tags: python, json, django

Есть колонка в модели `Names` и её значения `Ivan,Vasa` (`CharField`).

Сериализуя модель в json (стандартный `django.core.serializer`), получаю массив и вот отрывок массива нужного мне `{'Names': 'Ivan,Vasa'}`. А хотелось бы получить словарь имен в виде `{'Names': ['Ivan',Vasa']}`. В этом и заключается суть вопроса. View которая сериализует:

```
def get_tables(request):
    tables = Tables.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', tables)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

И `models`:

```
class Tables(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    columns = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    Names = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил эту проблему таким способом:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField

class Tables(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    columns = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    Names = JSONField()
```